# no implicit conversion of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to set default time to 2 hours from now. So I wrote this peace of code:

```
<%= f.datetime_select :starts_at, :default => { :hour => 2.hours.from_now, :minute => 0 }, :order => [:day, :month, :year] %>
```

I've got an error:

```
no implicit conversion of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone into Integer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.hours.from_now yields a ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone object but hour is expecting an Integer.

```
:hour => 2.hours.from_now.hour
```

I tried this and it works fine for me. Do you have a validation on your model which is causing it to fail?

Also this will not give you exactly 2 hours since you are setting the minute variable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with?

```
:hour => 2.hours.from_now.hour
```

I edited because you need the absolute hour.

Comment: Yes. I tried this too. I've got error: argument out of range